# How do I use regex to replace a sentence with paragraphs in Notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm a Notepad++ newbie and I have a report with multiple instances of this sentence

> All students with a C grade and below will not be allowed to join any outdoor trip.

I'd like to change the sentence to

> Due to change in policy, students with a C grade and below will not be joining any trip. This is to motivate weaker students.
>
> (Please contact us if you feel this is harsh).

I'm confused on the usage of `()` and `\n` in this instance.

Comment: Why don't you use regular search-and-replace for this? This is not really a job for regex.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a regex. Make the replace string :

Due to change in policy, students with a C grade and below will not be joining any trip. This is to motivate weaker students.\n\n(Please contact us if you feel this is harsh).

and choose search mode Extended, that should do the trick

Answer (score 3):

Ctrl + H

Search for:

> All students with a C grade and below
>   will not be allowed to join any
>   outdoor trip.

Replace with:

> Due to change in policy, students with
>   a C grade and below will not be
>   joining any trip.\n This is to
>   motivate weaker students.\n\n(Please
>   contact us if you feel this is harsh).

And make sure youe search modus is on extended

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ Regex can't handle rowbreaks very well.
But in your case you should not use Regex, but Extended.

Choose Search - Replace and check *Extended* as Search mode.
Then replace the text with:

> Due to change in policy, students with a C grade and below will not be joining any trip. This is to motivate weaker students.\n\n(Please contact us if you feel this is harsh)